# How to Limit Object inside Transparent Rectangle Area - FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am implementing designer functionality using [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) in my side. My Idea is to set the background image using setBackgroundImage from fabric, also i add specific area of transparent rectangle with size and position fetch from [JCrop](http://jcrop.com/). Now come to my question, i want to restrict the object placement within that specific area of transparent rectangle. Let say i want to add text/image/shapes that should be in that limited area, i able to implement the background image, position of transparent rectangle and even circle shape object but i unable to find details to limit object place it inside transparent rectangle and only in that region.

Here is my below code and working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz1pw3eh/19/), If you see it in fiddle the image where you need to select the cropping portion and below that canvas background with transparent rectangle which is the one of same like crop selection. Now i want to limit the object placement anything to be in that transparent rectangle, right now i can place object in anywhere in the canvas.

**HTML**

```
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595438337199-d50ba5072c7e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=330&q=80" id="target">

   <div class="canvas-container" style="position: relative; user-select: none;">
     <canvas id="c1" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc; position: absolute;  left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: none; user-select: none;"></canvas>
   </div>
```

**JS**

```
function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
  var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
  return {
    width: srcWidth * ratio,
    height: srcHeight * ratio,
    aspectratio: ratio
  };
}

jQuery(function($) {
    //alert("Testing");
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    var data = calculateAspectRatioFit(this.width, this.height, '400', '600');
    console.log(data);
    jQuery('#target').attr('width', data.width);
    jQuery('#target').attr('height', data.height);
    jQuery('#pdr-drawing-area').html("Aspect Ratio: " + data.aspectratio);
    const stage = Jcrop.attach('target');
    stage.listen('crop.change', function(widget, e) {
      const pos = widget.pos;
      console.log(pos.x, pos.y, pos.w, pos.h);
      //fabric js
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
      var center = canvas.getCenter();
      var img = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595438337199-d50ba5072c7e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=330&q=80';
      canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, function() {
        canvas.backgroundImage && canvas.backgroundImage.scaleToWidth(data.width);
        canvas.backgroundImage && canvas.backgroundImage.scaleToHeight(data.height);
        //canvas.sendToBack(img);
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
      console.log(pos.x * data.aspectratio);
      var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: pos.x,
        top: pos.y,
        fill: 'transparent',
        width: (pos.w),
        height: (pos.h),
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        stroke: "black",
        selectable: false,
        evented: false,
        //visible: false
      });



      canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 30,
        fill: '#f55',
        top: pos.y + 2,
        left: pos.x + 2
      }));

      canvas.add(rect);
      canvas.setHeight(data.height);
      canvas.setWidth(data.width);
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  },
   img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595438337199-d50ba5072c7e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=330&q=80';
});
```

Comment: You are asking to restrict a FabricJS object on this case a Circle to certain boundaries ... can you reduce your code example to just that.

Comment: Looking closer at your code... you have really not tried anything to restrict or detect movement in the canvas, to start you need `canvas.on("object:moving" ...`

Comment: How are the objects placed on the canvas? Are the users going to add something on a click event or are you just having an object and need to calculate where to place it? Is the placement the problem or are you looking to have a solution to move the object within the limited boundaries?

Comment: @AdamM. take a look at the fiddle, the objects are added to the canvas programmatically when the user sets the area in the "JCrop"  from the fiddle it looks like that is all done correctly. _ The issue seems to be with the "restrict the object placement" part ... but Vignesh has not provided any feedback

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Thanks for the key, as i haven't tried any with restriction part, i thought something available natively. Your Answer helps a lot to achieve desired result.

Comment: @AdamM Actually i was tried to set the rectangle transparent area in canvas. JCrop selection will be in backend and in frontend am set the transparent rectangle based on jcrop data(x, y axis and top, left position) now my question is to set any object inside the restriction(transparent rectangle) area as those object are selected by user in frontend(like shape, images etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to restrict movement in FabricJS.
I'm using the stateful property of the canvas, see `function objectMoving` below.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.stateful = true;

function inside(p, vs) {
    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i].x, yi = vs[i].y;
        var xj = vs[j].x, yj = vs[j].y;
        var intersect = yi > p.y !== yj > p.y && p.x < ((xj - xi) * (p.y - yi)) / (yj - yi) + xi;
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }
    return inside;
}

function getCoords(rect) {
    var coords = []
    coords.push(rect.aCoords.tl);
    coords.push(rect.aCoords.tr);
    coords.push(rect.aCoords.br);
    coords.push(rect.aCoords.bl);
    coords.push(rect.aCoords.tl);
    return coords;
}

function objectMoving(e) {
    var cCoords = getCoords(parent);
    var inBounds = inside({ x: e.target.left + 30, y: e.target.top + 30 }, cCoords);

    if (inBounds) {
        e.target.setCoords();
        e.target.saveState();
    } else {
        e.target.left = e.target._stateProperties.left;
        e.target.top = e.target._stateProperties.top;
    }
}

var boundary = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 310, height: 170,
    left: 5, top: 5,
    selectable: false,
    strokeDashArray: [5, 2],
    stroke: "blue",
    fill: "transparent"
});

var parent = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 250, height: 110,
    left: 35, top: 35,
    selectable: false,
    strokeDashArray: [2, 5],
    stroke: "black",
    fill: "transparent"
});

var child = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 30,
    fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
    top: 50, left: 50,
    hasControls: false,
});

canvas.add(boundary);
canvas.add(parent);
canvas.add(child);
canvas.on("object:moving", objectMoving);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="180"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

In the `function inside` I'm using the ray-casting algorithm, you can read more about it here:
https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon/blob/master/index.js
I prefer this algorithm because it opens the door for later allowing more complex shapes as the parent boundaries, it can work with a polygon of any shape.

If you need any clarifications on that code let me know.

---

Now you do need to integrate that into your project and dynamically change the parent boundaries as they change in the user in the "JCrop" selection

Comment: Can the circle be fully fit inside the transparent area? in your case it comes out of the transparent area. If it comes out can it be hidden and show only what is inside transparent rectangle?

Comment: There is no "transparent area" in my drawing... there are two rectangles. the blue one is the outside boundary that is the are the circle edges never exceeds, the black rectangle is the boundary relative to the center of the circle.  ... you can choose to not draw the black one if that is what you mean